# Trouble running nao_driver package

Tags: ros, nao-robot, naoqi, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been trying for a few days to run nao_driver package, with no sucess. I looked around for answers, but none of the solutions could help me.
Aparently, Naoqi is set up correctly, since I can import it with "import naoqi" in python.
However, when I try to run something like "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/nao/tools/pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.14-linux64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH NAO_IP=127.0.0.1 roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver_sim.launch" , I get the following errors:

> @florabranchi-Dell-System-XPS-15Z:~/nao/tools/pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.14-linux64$
> > LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/nao/tools/pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.14-linux64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> NAO_IP=127.0.0.1 roslaunch nao_driver
> nao_driver_sim.launch ... logging to
> /home/florabranchi/.ros/log/c37b6108-b373-11e3-beca-848f69cd2cc7/roslaunch-florabranchi-Dell-System-XPS-15Z-7419.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  *
> /nao_sensors/use_joint_sensors  *
> /rosdistro  * /rosversion
>
> NODES   /
> nao_behaviors (nao_driver/nao_behaviors.py)
> nao_controller (nao_driver/nao_controller.py)
> nao_leds (nao_driver/nao_leds.py)
> nao_sensors (nao_driver/nao_sensors.py)
> nao_speech (nao_driver/nao_speech.py)
> nao_tactile (nao_driver/nao_tactile.py)
> nao_walker (nao_driver/nao_walker.py)
>
> core service [/rosout] found
> process[nao_sensors-1]: started with
> pid [7437] process[nao_walker-2]:
> started with pid [7438] No handlers
> could be found for logger "rosout"
> process[nao_controller-3]: started
> with pid [7441] No handlers could be
> found for logger "rosout"
> process[nao_behaviors-4]: started with
> pid [7444]
> ================================================================================REQUIRED process [nao_sensors-1] has died!
> process has died [pid 7437, exit code
> 1, cmd
> /home/florabranchi/catkin_ws/src/nao_robot/nao_driver/nodes/nao_sensors.py --pip=127.0.0.1 --pport=9559 __name:=nao_sensors __log:=/home/florabranchi/.ros/log/c37b6108-b373-11e3-beca-848f69cd2cc7/nao_sensors-1.log]. log file:
> /home/florabranchi/.ros/log/c37b6108-b373-11e3-beca-848f69cd2cc7/nao_sensors-1*.log
> Initiating shutdown!
> ================================================================================ No handlers could be found for logger
> "rosout" cannot add process
> [nao_leds-5] after process monitor has
> been shut down No handlers could be
> found for logger "rosout"
> [nao_behaviors-4] killing on exit
> [nao_controller-3] killing on exit
> [nao_walker-2] killing on exit
> [nao_sensors-1] killing on exit

I have tried force_python:=true and it still doesn't work :(
It seems that the process just dies, and doesn't tell me the error.
Are those "No handlers could be found for logger "rosout" normal?

Does anyone have the same problem or can help me solving this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143846/trouble-running-nao_driver-package/) by [florabranchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/13796/florabranchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-03-25**:
Is there a reason why you add the pynaoqi module path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH? I think the path should only be in your PYTHONPATH, not LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-03-25**:
To (possibly) get more output, you could also try to run only the nao_sensors node: "rosrun nao_driver nao_sensors.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned by AHornung, your problem is that you need to do:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/nao/tools/pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.14-linux64:$PYTHONPATH
```

(and not LD_LIBRARY_PATH). The error you get (though totally unexplicit) is typical from not finding naoqi on your PYTHONPATH

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2014-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2014-08-01**:
And btw, the code just changed to give a normal error code. That should appear in the next release.